# VBA Range.Parent Navigation between different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing an application in MS Excel 2010, and I'm using VBA to create some drop downs.
I am trying to create a robust dynamic function that is able to do operations on Worksheets, (different tabs) based on the current tab.

For example I have tabs: `A, B, C, D, E`

If I am on `Worksheets("C")`, I want to pull values from the worksheet right before it, `Worksheets("B")`. If I am on `Worksheets("D")`, then I want to operate on values from `Worksheets("C")` etc...

I don't want to create a long hard-coded function that does a bunch of comparisons to see which is the current worksheet, and fetch values that way.

I am currently getting the name of the current range as such.

```
        Worksheets(someRange.Parent.Name)
```

**I'd like something like**: *(But, this is the incorrect syntax...)*

```
        Worksheets((someRange.Parent - 1).Name)
```

My question is, given a current Range, `someRange` how do I refer to other worksheets? What is the correct syntax?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Worksheets(someRange.Parent.Name)`

is simpler as:

`someRange.Parent`

Previous worksheet:

`someRange.Parent.Parent.Worksheets(someRange.Parent.Index-1)`

Have to add a check that you're not already on the first sheet...